# How to secure IdentityManager with IdentityServer v3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture, identityserver3

[Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/) released the new beta version of [IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) last week. There are quite some changes in the security model, so the configuration also changed.

He even took some videos ([Setting up ASP.NET Identity](https://vimeo.com/125426951) and [Security and IdentityManager](https://vimeo.com/125427106)) on how to configure the new version properly. These well explain the usage in a classic ASP.NET MVC application, and also ADFS setup, but I couldn't find any help or sample code about how to make it work side by side with [Identity Server v3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3).

Can you please share your experiences configuring IdMgr's remote access with the help of IdSrv3?

Comment: IdSrv3 is an STS; Managing users would need to be done on that system, not from within your application. Are you using IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @BradChristie. Actually, after posting this question, I spend some time on IdentityManager Gitter chatroom and solved this issue. Will post my answer now, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After posting that question, I opened an issue on Github and had some chat on [IdentityManager Gitter Chatroom](https://gitter.im/IdentityManager/IdentityManager), I managed to solve that issue.

There was a [sample host configuration](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Host/Startup.cs) in IdentityManager Github Source. Implementing the exact configuration on my project, now I can remotely connect to IdMgr using IdSrv3.

Hope that helpes someone.

Comment: Glad you made this work. I'm struggling with this and was wondering if you can shed more light on your configuration. 
What "client" have you used? and which "flow" you choose?
How did you get "access token" or "identity token" ?

Comment: Hi. It was a long time ago and I don't remember what I did exactly to make this work. Take a look at the sample host configuration link I gave you. It hold enough code to help me then...