# Secure IdentityManager with IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture, identitymanager

In my setup I have IdentityManager on the same host of IdentityServer.
All the required configuration is on database.

To create my setup I have taken in consideration [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29938538/431537) on stackoverflow.com and then followed all the regarding discussion on this [github issue](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/issues/122).

I have also subscribed to Gitter to find the conversation mentioned on the SO question referenced. My setup is almost identical to the one of @ilter.

However in my case I keep getting

> Error: You are not authorized to use this service.

By looking at the log I dont find any error but it seems that everything is ok

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:15:48.578 +01:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:15:48.587 +01:00 [Information] End authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:15:48.588 +01:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
2016-02-28 01:15:48.598 +01:00 [Debug] Protecting message: "{\"ReturnUrl\":\"https://localhost:44304/core/connect/authorize?client_id=idmgr_client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44304&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20idmgr&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DjVlpr2PjZWgTlrCDJdsIJvdfrhUBQhR4poOyPFrv0hXsxHmYajBzTy2EJJAj8PUgqi6iQzjgjX-hBb9CJU12rmR6xW_7exeh2aIEOObOXbVQ49OPbdIhSBKxha5kLWZw4iEuPEX6Ky5hoZbf9B2umZNPhh3HjsyxRZzqZoy4J2kijeza-1kEzUdhekvCj9Jat8_3QhvGWYvVQwA6fNneCm42w7sFCnljj6Sv1U8YIwBL2AMIi6d3yfQ-dQZ4ECVOVb53E_JgA8b-kVmIbwVcN-Re_8oyG6ebzU0GHAbygu4&nonce=635922153485579567.YjgxMzg2NjgtNWViMS00YjRlLWJhYTItZTY2YTA1NDgxODc1ODQyYWQ1ZjYtMTM2Yi00Yzc0LWE5YjItZTg3NTQwYzQzNDVk\",\"ClientId\":\"idmgr_client\",\"AcrValues\":[],\"Created\":635922153485649371}"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:15:48.636 +01:00 [Information] Login page requested
2016-02-28 01:15:48.657 +01:00 [Debug] signin message passed to login: "{
  \"ReturnUrl\": \"https://localhost:44304/core/connect/authorize?client_id=idmgr_client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44304&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20idmgr&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DjVlpr2PjZWgTlrCDJdsIJvdfrhUBQhR4poOyPFrv0hXsxHmYajBzTy2EJJAj8PUgqi6iQzjgjX-hBb9CJU12rmR6xW_7exeh2aIEOObOXbVQ49OPbdIhSBKxha5kLWZw4iEuPEX6Ky5hoZbf9B2umZNPhh3HjsyxRZzqZoy4J2kijeza-1kEzUdhekvCj9Jat8_3QhvGWYvVQwA6fNneCm42w7sFCnljj6Sv1U8YIwBL2AMIi6d3yfQ-dQZ4ECVOVb53E_JgA8b-kVmIbwVcN-Re_8oyG6ebzU0GHAbygu4&nonce=635922153485579567.YjgxMzg2NjgtNWViMS00YjRlLWJhYTItZTY2YTA1NDgxODc1ODQyYWQ1ZjYtMTM2Yi00Yzc0LWE5YjItZTg3NTQwYzQzNDVk\",
  \"ClientId\": \"idmgr_client\",
  \"IdP\": null,
  \"Tenant\": null,
  \"LoginHint\": null,
  \"DisplayMode\": null,
  \"UiLocales\": null,
  \"AcrValues\": [],
  \"Created\": 635922153485649371
}"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:15:48.676 +01:00 [Information] rendering login page
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.024 +01:00 [Information] Login page submitted
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.117 +01:00 [Information] Login credentials successfully validated by user service
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.123 +01:00 [Information] Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.127 +01:00 [Information] issuing primary signin cookie
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.131 +01:00 [Information] redirecting to: https://localhost:44304/core/connect/authorize?client_id=idmgr_client&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Flocalhost:44304&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid idmgr&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DjVlpr2PjZWgTlrCDJdsIJvdfrhUBQhR4poOyPFrv0hXsxHmYajBzTy2EJJAj8PUgqi6iQzjgjX-hBb9CJU12rmR6xW_7exeh2aIEOObOXbVQ49OPbdIhSBKxha5kLWZw4iEuPEX6Ky5hoZbf9B2umZNPhh3HjsyxRZzqZoy4J2kijeza-1kEzUdhekvCj9Jat8_3QhvGWYvVQwA6fNneCm42w7sFCnljj6Sv1U8YIwBL2AMIi6d3yfQ-dQZ4ECVOVb53E_JgA8b-kVmIbwVcN-Re_8oyG6ebzU0GHAbygu4&nonce=635922153485579567.YjgxMzg2NjgtNWViMS00YjRlLWJhYTItZTY2YTA1NDgxODc1ODQyYWQ1ZjYtMTM2Yi00Yzc0LWE5YjItZTg3NTQwYzQzNDVk
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.150 +01:00 [Information] Start authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.150 +01:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.165 +01:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"idmgr_client\",
  \"ClientName\": \"IdentityManager\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"https://localhost:44304\",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"https://localhost:44304\"
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"8029ac3e-72cb-4fc9-907b-eb99feecbbd6\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"id_token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"form_post\",
  \"Flow\": \"Implicit\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid idmgr\",
  \"State\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=jVlpr2PjZWgTlrCDJdsIJvdfrhUBQhR4poOyPFrv0hXsxHmYajBzTy2EJJAj8PUgqi6iQzjgjX-hBb9CJU12rmR6xW_7exeh2aIEOObOXbVQ49OPbdIhSBKxha5kLWZw4iEuPEX6Ky5hoZbf9B2umZNPhh3HjsyxRZzqZoy4J2kijeza-1kEzUdhekvCj9Jat8_3QhvGWYvVQwA6fNneCm42w7sFCnljj6Sv1U8YIwBL2AMIi6d3yfQ-dQZ4ECVOVb53E_JgA8b-kVmIbwVcN-Re_8oyG6ebzU0GHAbygu4\",
  \"Nonce\": \"635922153485579567.YjgxMzg2NjgtNWViMS00YjRlLWJhYTItZTY2YTA1NDgxODc1ODQyYWQ1ZjYtMTM2Yi00Yzc0LWE5YjItZTg3NTQwYzQzNDVk\",
  \"SessionId\": \"3c7c7e15d39b88d0989e7051b02502bd\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"idmgr_client\",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://localhost:44304\",
    \"response_mode\": \"form_post\",
    \"response_type\": \"id_token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid idmgr\",
    \"state\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=jVlpr2PjZWgTlrCDJdsIJvdfrhUBQhR4poOyPFrv0hXsxHmYajBzTy2EJJAj8PUgqi6iQzjgjX-hBb9CJU12rmR6xW_7exeh2aIEOObOXbVQ49OPbdIhSBKxha5kLWZw4iEuPEX6Ky5hoZbf9B2umZNPhh3HjsyxRZzqZoy4J2kijeza-1kEzUdhekvCj9Jat8_3QhvGWYvVQwA6fNneCm42w7sFCnljj6Sv1U8YIwBL2AMIi6d3yfQ-dQZ4ECVOVb53E_JgA8b-kVmIbwVcN-Re_8oyG6ebzU0GHAbygu4\",
    \"nonce\": \"635922153485579567.YjgxMzg2NjgtNWViMS00YjRlLWJhYTItZTY2YTA1NDgxODc1ODQyYWQ1ZjYtMTM2Yi00Yzc0LWE5YjItZTg3NTQwYzQzNDVk\"
  }
}"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.170 +01:00 [Information] Creating Implicit Flow response.
2016-02-28 01:17:42.170 +01:00 [Debug] Creating identity token
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.170 +01:00 [Information] Getting claims for identity token for subject: 8029ac3e-72cb-4fc9-907b-eb99feecbbd6
2016-02-28 01:17:42.177 +01:00 [Debug] Creating JWT identity token
2016-02-28 01:17:42.189 +01:00 [Debug] Adding client "idmgr_client" to client list cookie for subject "8029ac3e-72cb-4fc9-907b-eb99feecbbd6"
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.190 +01:00 [Information] End authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.190 +01:00 [Information] Posting to https://localhost:44304
2016-02-28 01:17:42.190 +01:00 [Debug] Using DefaultViewService to render authorization response HTML
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 2016-02-28 01:17:42.438 +01:00 [Information] User is authenticated from Cookies
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It maybe your user doesn't have the role: **IdentityManagerAdministrator**. In IdentityManager web API config I can see following authorize filter where admin role name is IdentityManagerAdministrator.

```
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = options.SecurityConfiguration.AdminRoleName });
```

Try adding that role claim to your logged in user, or change the filter to check for any other role your current user has.

Comment: It seems that I really needed some rest! Thank you for the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

it seems you don't have the correct Admin role

you can specify the `AdminRoleName` in the `SecurityConfiguration`

```
app.Map("/idm", manageApp => {
    manageApp.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions {
        SecurityConfiguration = new HostSecurityConfiguration {
            // Identity Manager Role
            AdminRoleName = "IdmAdmin"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yep. +1 for mentioning the configuration option.