# How do identityserver permissions work?

Tags: identityserver4, identitymanager

Scenario 1: Assume I have angular client with implicit grant type. I am also using asp.net identity to log in with database users. I log in as user Bob. I access my list of cars. For each car I have an option to edit my car. Each row has edit button and id of car.

Example of get url in each row: http://localhost:5000/cars/id/1

Let's say I enter randomly some id of car:
http://localhost:5000/cars/id/345 which is someone else's user car.

How does identity server protects other user data in this situation?

Scenario 2: let's have identity manager set up with identity server openid authentication. Which username and password are we authenticating to gain access identity manager to manage users ? If it is user from aspnet identity database then every user inside there can access identity manager...?

Comment: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

They don’t.
It’s not responsibility of Identity Server.
Identity server main responsibility is to take care of Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1**

Authorization is not part of identity server except for basic client/scope based authorization defined in OAuth. Identity server just handles the authentication part. Have a look here for implement authorization on an asp.net core app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased

Basically, Identity server gives the user identity. So you can validate if that user has access to the given resource.

**Scenario 2**

You can define users with certain role claim(e.g. Role:IdentityManagerAdministrator) in your user store, and validate if the logged in user has that role in identityManager. see 
[Secure IdentityManager with IdentityServer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677334/secure-identitymanager-with-identityserver3)

Comment: where can I find a framework that handles authorization/permission management? Did someone build this on top of IdentityServer?